# Thymeleaf - Multiple choice form

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf, bootstrap-select

I use Java, Thymeleafm, Bootstrap and bootstrap-select.
My repo is here https://github.com/realsony/thymeleaf

My Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
//@ResponseBody //can be deleted due to thymeleaf
public String start() {
    return "start";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String startPost(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    String productA = request.getParameter("Products");
    System.out.println("product: " + productA);
    return "start";
}
```

And that is my HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template :: head">
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="template :: body"></div>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="start.html">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select th:name="Products" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                <option th:value="Glas">Glas</option>
                <option th:value="Table">Table</option>
                <option th:value="Fork">Fork</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button th:type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**My problem**

Actually the user can select 1-4 products here.
As soon as he clicks one product, it should be saved in the controller.
But it is not working. At the Moment the reference "Products" only deliver one selection and not more.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: how are you sending the choice to the controller?

Comment: that is my question :) my idea was, that by clicking on a product option, the option will be saved in the Controller. By unselecting the Option it should be deleted again.

Answer (score 0):

first write two method in your Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save (HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
//save code goes here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String delete(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
//delete code goes here
}
```

then for select send ajax request to /save
and for deselect send ajax request to /delete